# widthMeasureSpec is 0 when in HorizontalScrollView

Tags: android, custom-view

I'm writing a custom view in Android. Since I need precise size management, I've overridden onMeasure. Its documentation says, that View.MeasureSpec.getMode returns one of three values, defined as constants. But when my view was placed inside HorizontalScrollView, widthMeasureSpec was 0 - I was unable to get both mode and size from it.

What is even weirder is that this parameter was 0 even if I explicitly defined width for my view.

Why does it happen, how should I interpret the 0 value and what should I do in this particular case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`0` means the mode is `UNSPECIFIED`. This means you can be as big as you want, which makes sense since it is a `ScrollView`...intended for a `View` bigger than your actual screen.

Being unspecified, you don't have to care about the size, this is why it is `0`.

If you look at the source of `HorizontalScrollView` you can also see that it just passes `width: 0, UNSPECIFIED` to the child:

```
@Override
protected void measureChild(View child, int parentWidthMeasureSpec, int parentHeightMeasureSpec) {
    ViewGroup.LayoutParams lp = child.getLayoutParams();

    int childWidthMeasureSpec;
    int childHeightMeasureSpec;

    childHeightMeasureSpec = getChildMeasureSpec(parentHeightMeasureSpec, mPaddingTop
            + mPaddingBottom, lp.height);

    childWidthMeasureSpec = MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(0, MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED);

    child.measure(childWidthMeasureSpec, childHeightMeasureSpec);
}
```

---

To get the child view as big as the parent you can use `fillViewPort` from xml or java which will lead to a call with mode `EXACTLY`:

```
if (!mFillViewport) {
    return;
}
// ...
int childWidthMeasureSpec = MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(width, MeasureSpec.EXACTLY);
```

This is one way to handle your child view being as big as the `ScrollView`.