# onMeasure returning widthMeasureSpec = 0 in HorizontalScrollView in Android 6

Tags: android

I believe my problem is related to this: [widthMeasureSpec is 0 when in HorizontalScrollView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35589320/widthmeasurespec-is-0-when-in-horizontalscrollview)
Long story short, I'm trying to create a custom horizontal scroll view. At some point, I'm overriding

```
protected void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec)
```

And while this works fine in Android >= 7, I'm getting a value of 0 for widthMeasureSpec in Android <= 6.
The code for measureChild changed between API 23 and 24:

In API 23:

```
childWidthMeasureSpec = MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(0, MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED);
```

In API 24:

```
final int childWidthMeasureSpec = MeasureSpec.makeSafeMeasureSpec(
                Math.max(0, MeasureSpec.getSize(parentWidthMeasureSpec) - horizontalPadding),
MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED);
```

I have tried to get the width from the parent view using a getter, but it is not working as expected as only some calls get the correct width. I also tried to override measureChild in the parent and putting the newest code there, with no luck:

```
@Override
protected void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec) {
    super.onMeasure(widthMeasureSpec, heightMeasureSpec);
    measureChild(getTouchInterceptTextView(), widthMeasureSpec, heightMeasureSpec);
}

@Override
protected void measureChild(View child, int parentWidthMeasureSpec,
                            int parentHeightMeasureSpec) {
    ViewGroup.LayoutParams lp = child.getLayoutParams();

    final int horizontalPadding = getPaddingLeft() + getPaddingRight();
    final int childWidthMeasureSpec = MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(
            Math.max(0, MeasureSpec.getSize(parentWidthMeasureSpec) - horizontalPadding),
            MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED);

    final int childHeightMeasureSpec = getChildMeasureSpec(parentHeightMeasureSpec,
            getPaddingTop() + getPaddingBottom(), lp.height);
    child.measure(childWidthMeasureSpec, childHeightMeasureSpec);
}
```

My wholes files are here: https://github.com/AdrienPoupa/VinylMusicPlayer/commit/ba0dfae7dd03771f3625b8393927986aad552e2a

The important part being:

```
<com.poupa.vinylmusicplayer.views.TouchInterceptHorizontalScrollView
                    android:id="@+id/title_scrollview"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

                    <com.poupa.vinylmusicplayer.views.AutoTruncateTextView
                        android:id="@+id/title"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:fontFamily="sans-serif"
                        android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Subhead" />

</com.poupa.vinylmusicplayer.views.TouchInterceptHorizontalScrollView>
```

The onMeasure function is in AutoTruncateTextView. I can get the measures in TouchInterceptHorizontalScrollView but that does not seem to help. I tried to add android:fillViewport="true" in the XML for TouchInterceptHorizontalScrollView, AutoTruncateTextView and both but it did not change the calculation.

What can I do to get the proper value of widthMeasureSpec in Android 6 and below?

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After many tries, it seems to be working by adding the following snippet to AutoTruncateTextView's onMeasure:

```
if (textBoundsWidth == 0) {
            textBoundsWidth =  getTouchInterceptFrameLayout().getMeasuredWidth();
        }
```

Basically, getting the width of the TouchInterceptFrameLayout, that is the 2nd level of the XML file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="72dp"
    android:foreground="?attr/rectSelector"
    tools:ignore="UnusedAttribute">

    <!-- for getSwipeableContainerView() -->
    <com.poupa.vinylmusicplayer.views.TouchInterceptFrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/dummy_view"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">
```

and keeping the code posted above otherwise the truncate mechanism does not work anymore.